# Sorting list without using import libraries

Tags: python, list

How do I sort the list:

```
[{'2': [{'cid': 26363}]}, {'1': [{'cid': 26363}]}, {'3': [{'cid': 26363}]}]
```

In the order:

```
1,2,3
```

Without importing libraries?

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by providing `key` in `sort` function, you can achieve this as

```
x =[{'2': [{'cid': 26363}]}, {'1': [{'cid': 26363}]}, {'3': [{'cid': 26363}]}]
x.sort(key=lambda x:[int(i) for i in x.keys()][0])
print(x)
```

output:

```
  [{'1': [{'cid': 26363}]}, {'2': [{'cid': 26363}]}, {'3': [{'cid': 26363}]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sorted to do this. It feels a bit clumsy though and i would rather do it with itertools:

```
x = [{'2': [{'cid': 26363}]}, {'1': [{'cid': 26363}]}, {'3': [{'cid': 26363}]}]
sorted(x, key=lambda a: int(list(a.keys())[0]))
```

The assumption here is that you only have one key per dictionary in your list, which may not be the case.

Comment: this is wrong solution, will fail when the value is 11, 22, 3  you need to convert string type to  int type first @thomasopopop

Comment: good point, i hadn't thought of that case